# Cannot add run to a textblock in foreach loop

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I building a UWP application.
And what I'm trying to achieve is to show a tweet and if there are any urls in the tweet, have it render as a hyperlink text.
So what I'm doing is going through the text and finding urls and assigning runs into a textblock and then assigning it to the textblock on the page.

Code behind:

```
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();

        Regex url_regex = new Regex(@"(http:\/\/([\w.]+\/?)\S*)" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        MatchCollection collection = url_regex.Matches(tweet);

        int index = 0;

        //for test only
        Run r = new Run();
        r.Text = "int";
        block.Inlines.Add(r);

        foreach (Match item in collection)
        {

            Run run = new Run();
            run.Text = tweet.Substring(index , item.Index);
            //error occurs here.
            block.Inlines.Add(run);

            index = item.Index;

            run.Text = tweet.Substring(index , item.Length);
            Hyperlink h = new Hyperlink();
            h.Inlines.Add(run);
            block.Inlines.Add(h);

            index = item.Index + item.Length;
        }

        r.Text = tweet.Substring(index , tweet.Length);
        block.Inlines.Add(r);

        blok = block;
```

the Xaml:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox Name="input"
                PlaceholderText="input here" />
    <TextBlock Name="blok"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I don't understand what's going on because the test run adding is working fine because it is outside the foreach loop. Once the run is added to the inlines in a **foreachloop** it throws an error saying that :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No installed components were detected.

Element is already the child of another element.
```

There are other questions on the internet on this topic but I didn't get a good solution.

Comment: block.Inlines.Add(r) was done twice ... once before and once after the loop ... is that why?

Comment: no the before one was added to test .. and as i guessed there was no error how many times u add it outside the foreach block ..

Comment: and it only gives error once its inside the foreach loop

Comment: Have you tried creating the Run class and init using the constructor ? i.e run = new Run(strText) ?

Comment: In the loop you are also adding the same Run instance `run` to the Inlines of a Hyperlink element. That won't work. You'll have to create a new instance.

Comment: theere is no constructor .. it only has a empty constructor.

Comment: but the error occurs even before reaching that statement

Comment: I'm also not sure what you expect to happen when you call `blok = block;`.

Comment: Why is that so can i have some explanation plss... and from blok = block i'm setting my textblock that is in xaml

Comment: `blok = block` won't set the text of the TextBlock that you created in XAML. Either you directly modify `blok.Inlines` or you remove `blok` from the StackPanel's Children and then add `block` to the Children.

Comment: yea i'm kinda trying this thing .. just found out that it's not happening .. thank u .. btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to assign the same `Run` element to 2 parents: the `TextBlock` and the `Hyperlink`.

```
Run run = new Run();
run.Text = tweet.Substring(index , item.Index);
//error occurs here.
block.Inlines.Add(run);

index = item.Index;

run.Text = tweet.Substring(index , item.Length);
Hyperlink h = new Hyperlink();
h.Inlines.Add(run);
block.Inlines.Add(h);

index = item.Index + item.Length;
```

While these are 2 different runs, so change your loop to:

```
foreach (Match item in collection)
{

    Run runRegularText = new Run();
    runRegularText.Text = tweet.Substring(index, item.Index);
    block.Inlines.Add(runRegularText);

    index = item.Index;

    Run runHyperlink = new Run();
    runHyperlink.Text = tweet.Substring(index, item.Length);
    Hyperlink h = new Hyperlink();
    h.Inlines.Add(runHyperlink);
    block.Inlines.Add(h);

    index = item.Index + item.Length;
}
```